# Show the following holds for $c\leq 1$: $e^{ck^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!} \leq M, \quad \text{for } k = 1, \dots, n.$ for some constant $M$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

Show that the following inequality holds for $c\leq1$:
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
e^{ck^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!} \leq M, \quad \text{for $k = 1, 
\dots, n$}
\end{equation}
for some constant $M$.

Interestingly, R result shows that when $c>1$, $e^{ck^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. I am wondering if this can be proven.

Hint A: According to the concise and ingenious answer by @Qiaochu Yuan, ($1$) holds for $c\leq \frac12$, and $M$ can be chosen as $1$.

Hint B: $\frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}$ is just $\binom{2n}{n-k}/\binom{2n}{n}$. It might be related to asymptotic behavior for the binomial coefficient. I find the following truths.

1. $\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ for $n$ sufficiently large.
2. $\binom{n}{k} \sim \binom{n}{n/2}e^{-d^2/(2n)} \sim \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\frac12 n\pi}} e^{-d^2/(2n)}$ if $|\frac{n}{2}-k|=o(n^{2/3})$.
3. $\binom{n}{k}\sim (\frac{ne}{k})^k \cdot (2\pi k)^{-1/2} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{k^2}{2n}(1+o(1))\right)$ if $n$ is large and $k$ is $o(n)$.

see [Wikipedia page for binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas), and p57-60,66 for the book below.

*Spencer, Joel; Florescu, Laura*, Asymptopia, Student Mathematical Library 71. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS).

ps: In my previous version, the right-hand side of ($1$) is $1$, which is incorrect. I have replaced it with a bounded constant. Thanks, @Qiaochu Yuan, @Mostafa Ayaz, and @Anne Bauval for pointing this out!

This is a simple R code just for checking.

```
n = 1e5
k = 1:n
c = 1.01  #c=.99
a = 2*lfactorial(n)-lfactorial(n+k)-lfactorial(n-k)
b = c*k^2/n
P = exp(a+b)
max(P)
```

Comment: a) Why not just ask for $e^{k^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!} \leq 1\; \text{for } k = 1, \dots, n$, without the $c$? b) Where did you find that statement? c) Did the hint belong to or is it from you?

Comment: Yes, that would make it simpler. But I would like to prove $e^{ck^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!} \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ for $c>1$, for the next step.

Comment: a) This would not prevent from that.

Comment: b) I want this statement in my proof. I am confident it is correct and the R code justify this. c) The hint is from Wikipedia page binomial coefficient, as the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar but weaker statement that we can actually prove. We have

$$\begin{eqnarray} \log \frac{n!^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!} &=& \log \frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}{(n+k)(n+k-1) \dots (n+1)} \\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^k \log \frac{n-k+i}{n+i} \\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^k \log \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n+i} \right) \\
 &\le& \sum_{i=1}^k - \frac{k}{n+i} \\
 &\le& - \frac{k^2}{n+k} \end{eqnarray}.$$

where we used the inequality $\log (1 + x) \le x$ for $x \in (-1, \infty)$ on the fourth line.

Comment: How to show the last inequality?

Comment: I think the opposite inequality holds since $\frac{1}{n+i}<\frac{1}{n}$. Also, there is a missing $n!$ in the first fraction.

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake. Apparently the desired inequality is just false. I've edited with a salvage.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That would be very much helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The statement for $k=c=1$ is
$$e^{1/n}\le1+\frac1n,$$
which is false.

Edit: this was the first correct answer to the original question (see the end of the post above).

Comment: Thanks, I was getting very confused for a bit there...

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct. Let me revise the RHS with a constant M.

Comment: @Isstat It is unfair to modify a post after receiving answers. You should either make explicit in your post both your previous question and your new version, or (less confusing) edit a new post (and rollback that one as it was before)

Comment: Sorry let me state clear in my post

Comment: Thanks for your continuous attention to this question. For your updated answer, it answers the behavior for $k\sim n$. For $k$ being $o(n)$, I guess more statements are required. From my R result, it seems LHS of ($1$) goes up when $k$ is 1 to roughly $\sqrt{n}$, and after $k\geq\sqrt{n}$, LHS seems to go down and converge to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a miskate again. I rolled back.

Comment: It seems $e^{k^2/n}$ increases, the binomial part decreases, and the maximum is achieved at roughly $k=\sqrt{n}$ (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

This inequality does not hold for every $C=k=1$. To prove this, note that
$$
e^{ck^2/n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}|_{C=k=1}=e^\frac{1}{n}\frac{n}{n+1},
$$
which is always $\ge 1$.

Continuing with general $C$ and $k=1$, the inequality must hold only if
$$
e^\frac{C}{n}\frac{n}{n+1}\le 1 \implies e^\frac{C}{n}\le 1+\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Starting with $n=1$, one finds a necessary condition for $C$ as $C\le \ln 2$.

Comment: That's alright. Science grows with contribution, by all means :D